# reading double from dynamically unsigned char array

Tags: c

I'm going to read data directly from a "gz" format file. Using "zlib" in c, I read the data from gz file and now I have an unsigned char array namely "str". I want to extract double numbers using "sscanf". here is my code:

```
printf("%s\n", str);
double d1,d2,d3;
sscanf(str, "%lf %lf %lf", &d1, &d2, &d3);
printf("%lf\n", &d1);
printf("%lf\n", &d2);
printf("%lf\n", &d3);
```

and the output is:

```
23.323 1111.232 434434.1
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
```

it seems I have successfully read str from gz file, but I cannot read doubles from str.

Comment: trr with `%1d`  instead of`%1f`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work. This is because `%lf` expect a `double` value and you were passing a pointer to a `double` value.

```
printf("%lf\n", d1);
printf("%lf\n", d2);
printf("%lf\n", d3);
```

Comment: I think you should explain the change.